# How can i edit row and update row from grdiview which contain manually inserted values? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have done "edit" values in gridview which i inserted values manually in the gridview.I have a single gridview and outside gridview i have "textbox", "dragdroplist" and two "checboxes".Here is my gridview image 
[image]
in which i put values in "textbox" and also select value from "dragdroplist" and "checkboxes" and then press "Insert" button ,then values inserted in gridview manually.There is no database connectivity.I have done delete actions and edit action successfully,but when i click edit then row is edit but "Data Type" column have single "textbox"  but i want "data type" column have "dragdroplist" which i used in insert values.But i want to edit and update row in gridview,How can i do this?
Here is my aspx code :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
            AutoGenerateEditButton="True" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" 
            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" 
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" /></asp:GridView>

    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="137px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="20px" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="140px">
        <asp:ListItem>int</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Varchar</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Null" runat="server" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Primary" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Insert" 
        style="margin-left: 59px" Width="56px" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Height="33px" style="margin-left: 76px" 
        Text="Create Table" Width="94px" />
</form>
```

and here is my aspx.cs code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("ID", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Data Type", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Allow Null", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Primary Key", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        Session["MyDataTable"] = dt;

    }
}


protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    DataRow row1 = t.NewRow();

    row1["ID"] = t.Rows.Count + 1;
    row1["Column Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
    row1["Data Type"] = DropDownList1.Text;
    row1["Allow Null"] = Null.Checked == true ? "true" : "false";
    row1["Primary Key"] = Primary.Checked == true ? "true" : "false";
    t.Rows.Add(row1);

    Session["MyDataTable"] = t;
    GridView2.DataSource = t;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
 protected void GridView2_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
        DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
        t.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        GridView2.DataSource = t;
        GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-AutoGenerateDeleteButton-with-Delete-Confirmation-example.aspx and http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/29/updating-deleting-records-using-gridview-control

Comment: Soory this articles include database commands and queries but my gridview is simple not included any database commands etc

Comment: That doesn't matter... as you have your DataTable in session you can get the id and remove or edit the datatable. let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Just tell me edit and update code?I've done delete functionality

Answer (score 1):

On edit you need to hook to `OnRowEditing` event of gridview :

```
protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    this.BindGrid();
}
```

When updating hook to `OnRowUpdating` event where you will get the row details, from there search your datatable by `ID` and edit it :

```
protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
    string columnName = (row.Cells[2].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string dataType = (row.Cells[3].Controls[0] as DropDownList).Text;

    // edit DataTable...
}
```

Comment: Soory,it's not working,here is error snapshot http://hostthenpost.org/uploads/913779237087f4eac11d910ae81b8f76.png

Comment: check e.RowIndex what is the value? is ID a Textbox in your gridview? if so do same as columnName i.e. cast to TextBox

Comment: I just want when i click on edit then "Data Type" Column contain "dragdroplist" ,How can i do it?